# How to fix empty dashboard screen in Knowage?

Tags: docker, jndi, slf4j, tomcat8, fiware-knowage

I try to get knowage running in a docker environment. After several issues to get knowage running I finally managed to log in. After some more issues I was also able to connect knowage to a fiware orion context browser.

However, when I try to add a cockpit to my workspace, I receive an empty content page. The knowage navigation is still visible and working. This looks like this:

[Knowage issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8MK8.png)

I run docker-compose following the official description (https://hub.docker.com/r/knowagelabs/knowage-server-docker). The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
    knowage:
        image: knowagelabs/knowage-server-docker:6.3.3
        links:
            - knowagedb:db
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        environment:
            - WAIT_MYSQL=true

    knowagedb:
        image: mysql:5.6
        environment:
            - MYSQL_USER=username
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=userpassword
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=knowagedb
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
```

I regognized two issues in my docker log that might correspond to this behaviour:

First:

```
knowage_1    | SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
knowage_1    | SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
knowage_1    | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Second:

```
knowage_1    | 03-Apr-2019 07:57:50.345 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
knowage_1    |  javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManagerFactory]
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:66)
knowage_1    |  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:839)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:138)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:145)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:110)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:82)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:395)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:339)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:786)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:687)
knowage_1    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
knowage_1    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
knowage_1    |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
knowage_1    |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
knowage_1    | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.myfoo.commonj.work.FooWorkManagerFactory
knowage_1    |  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
knowage_1    |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
knowage_1    |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
knowage_1    |  at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:61)
knowage_1    |  ... 22 more
knowage_1    |
```

Any support to get this running is HIGHLY appreciated.

Thanks, 
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself.

I needed to set the optional parameter "PUBLIC_ADDRESS" in the docker-compose file ...

```
    knowage:
        image: knowagelabs/knowage-server-docker:6.3.3
        links:
            - knowagedb:db
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        environment:
            - WAIT_MYSQL=true
            - PUBLIC_ADDRESS=localhost

    knowagedb:
        image: mysql:5.6
        environment:
            - MYSQL_USER=username
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=userpassword
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=knowagedb
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
```

I found this out as many others had problems as they did not define the basic urls correctly. So I just added "localhost" to the containers' "public_address" environment